# How to change digital experience site template

Tags: community, digital-experience, salesforce-sites

I am really struggling to find a way on how to change my site template, i created it with Microsite (LWR). I thought it could have been from administration section:
[image]

I cant see the option there. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_template_change.htm&type=5) that the problem is with templates that are (LWR) when selecting this type of templates is not possible to change them later on.

When template is not (LWR) they can be easily changed from:

[image: Change template]